# Could you help me find out first and second partial derivatives $u=f(x,\frac{x}y)$

Tags: calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus

I understand that to find the first and second partial derivates of $u=f(x,\frac{x}y)$ I need to use chain rule. However I do not fully understand the meaning of superscripts in these solutions: [answer](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f(x,%20x%2Fy)%20derivative) and [answer](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f(x,%20x%2Fy)%20second%20derivative).

Comment: $f^{(1,0)}$ means $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and $f^{(0,1)}$ means $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}.$

Comment: I would use it for first derivative wrt first argument of f and first derivative wrt second argument of f, but I don't know if wolfram does that.

Comment: OK. I got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If $v=f(a,b)$ then the first and second derivatives are given by
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{ \partial v } {\partial a} =f^{(1,0)} \\
\frac{ \partial v } {\partial b} =f^{(0,1)} \\
\frac{ \partial^2 v } {\partial a^2} =f^{(2,0)} \\
\frac{ \partial^2 v } {\partial a \partial b} =f^{(1,1)} \\
\frac{ \partial^2 v } {\partial b^2} =f^{(0,2)} \\
\end{eqnarray*}
In your case $u =f(x, \frac{x}{y})$ , this will give
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{ \partial u } {\partial x} &=& f^{(1,0)}+ \frac{1}{y} f^{(0,1)} \\
\frac{ \partial u } {\partial y}  &=&  -\frac{x}{y^2}f^{(0,1)} \\
\frac{ \partial^2 u } {\partial x^2}  &=& f^{(2,0)}+ \frac{2}{y}f^{(1,1)} + \frac{1}{y^2}f^{(0,2)}\\
\frac{ \partial^2 u } {\partial x \partial y}  &=& \cdots \\
\frac{ \partial^2 u } {\partial y^2}  &=& \cdots \\
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: OK. I got it. Thanks.